# Horizontal scrollbar inside angular-material (mat-tab) using FlexBox Grid

Tags: sass, responsive-design, angular-material, horizontal-scrolling, mat-tab

I am trying to implement a horizontal scroll bar to display images , but the width of the wrapper (scroll-container) container is overflowing. I also need to use FlexBox grid to make it responsive for different screen sizes.

Structure for HTML & SCSS is as given below. The container must be inside a mat-tab-group (Angular Material).
div 'item' will contain multiple items.

I am running it on chrome and have checked the inspector, apparently the mat-tab-body-wrapper display: flex property is causing this issue.
Is there any work around for this issue?

HTML

```
  <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="First"> 
     <div class='row scroll-container'>
           <div class='col-xs-5 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-12'>
             <div class='horizontal-slider'>
               <div class='slider-container'>
                 <div class='item'>
                   <img src='' alt=''>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
```

SCSS

```
 .scroll-container {
            margin: 8px 0 0 0;
           
    .horizontal-slider {
       display: flex;
       overflow-y: hidden;
       max-width: inherit;
       overflow-x: scroll;
       box-sizing: border-box;

    .slider-container {
      
             .item {
               display: flex;
               margin-right: 8px;
        
               img {
                 width: 124px;
                 height: 124px;
               }
             }
        
           }
         }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most effective solution would be as shown below. Alongside the flex-nowrap you need to set the overflow attribute to prevent the whole page expanding.

With overflow property:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <h6>Bootstrap 4 horizontally scrollable card groups</h6>
 <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap overflow-auto">
      <div class="card card-block mx-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
      <div class="card card-block mx-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>
      <div class="card card-block mx-2" style="min-width: 300px;">Card</div>            
</div>
```

Comment: I need to do it using flexbox grid and not Bootstrap.

Comment: @NikhilMore `I need to do it using flexbox grid and not Bootstrap` add such to the question body.

Comment: Set .horizontal-slider{display:flex;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll}